# Networking not working fresh install ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: networking, server, 14.04

I just installed a fresh version of ubuntu server 14.04....

the installer was able to connect and download from the internet just fine and then when it rebooted it waited a while for the network connection but then booted without it.

ifconfig was telling me that only the loopback interface was working

i checked the names of my interfaces and linux was giving my ethernet configuration the name em1 instead of eth0

i changed my /etc/network/interfaces file to say em1 instead of eth0 and now I can connect to the local network for ssh but ping is failing and i can't use apt-get

is this something related to 14.04? Can I make this work or should I download an older version of ubuntu server?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your /etc/network/interfaces file for troubleshooting.

Comment: mine too. I can't add a static ip in the normal fashion.